# OUtlook in browser in win 10, dark mode, loses highlight color for slelected item, is there a darkish mode that fixes this?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook

I tried using dark mode theme and high contrast in win 10, but in both cases
when opening outlook in a browser window, you lose the ability to see what item you have selected, and what items are unread.

Is there a win10 theme, or even just an outlook theme with a darkish background that doesn't flatten out the selected and unread colors?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that it is not able to be changed. The custom display settings that provided by Outlook on the web are limited and there is no existed options for us to modify the setting about not flatten out the selected items and unread colors, you could try more custom settings if using Outlook desktop client.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Thanks for your understanding and support.